# Implementing translator using ANTLR by embedding semantic actions as Java code in the g4 grammar file

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

Trying to edit the below grammar and define the semantic actions required to translate arithmetic expressions written in the language defined below into postfix notation.

```
grammar Expr;
 
expr: expr ('*'|'/') term
    | expr ('+'|'-') term
    | term
    ;
term: '('expr')'
    | ID
    | NUM
    ;

ID: [a-z]+;
NUM: [0-9]+;

WS:  [\t\r\n]+->skip;
```

To implement the translator I'm embedding semantic actions as Java code in the g4 grammar file by using the push and pop operations of a stack. But when compiling I'm hit with a bunch of errors.

Here is what I have so far:

```
grammar Expr;
 
expr: expr (op=('*'|'/') term
  { Stack<String> s = new Stack<String>();
             s.push($op.text);
             s.push($term.text);
    String result = s.pop() + s.pop() + s.pop();
             $expr.text = result;
          }
   ) 
    | expr (op=('+'|'-') term
  { Stack<String> s = new Stack<String>();
             s.push($op.text);
             s.push($term.text);
    String result = s.pop() + s.pop() + s.pop();
             $expr.text = result;
          }
   )
    | term
    ;
term: '('expr')' { Stack<String> s = new Stack<String>();
     s.push($expr.text);
  String result = s.pop();
     $term.text = result;
   }
    | ID {Stack<String> s = new Stack<String>();
    s.push($ID.text);
 String result = s.pop();
    $term.text = result;
   } 

    | NUM {Stack<String> s = new Stack<String>();
    s.push($NUM.text);
 String result = s.pop();
    $term.text = result;
   } 
    ;

ID: [a-z]+;
NUM: [0-9]+;

WS:  [\t\r\n]+->skip;
```

When compiling I'm hit with an error block

[image]

I'm not sure how to fix this or if there's a better way to implement.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `$ctx.getText(result);`? The method `getText()` returns a string, it does not accept a string as a parameter.

Comment: Oh yeah my bad, I was testing it out. I edited the code to it's original state though I get an error of unknown attribute text for rule... so i was looking for an alternative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of issues here:

0 - Bart already mentioned how to import Stack, and that you can't assign to $term.text.

1 - If you want ANTLR to parse with the proper order of evaluation, you'll need `expr` on both sides of your operator alternatives.

2 - in the rule `expr (op=('*'|'/') term)` (omitting the action code), the `(` and `)` have no impact.

3 - your `WS` rule didn't include the space character.

4 - **always** initiate your parsing with a rule the ends with one EOF (this forces the parser to attempt to consume all of the input.  Without it, ANTLR may "stop short" if that's all it can recognize.

5 - You don't really need to create a new Stack instance in every action (the way you're pushing and popping in your actions basically just uses that stack as a place to define temp values, and doing no real processing between pushing and popping.). A global stack, however, can be used to good effect.

With all of those things in mind...

```
grammar Expr
    ;

@header {
import java.util.Stack;

}

@members {
Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
}

start: expr EOF;

expr
    : expr op = ('*' | '/') expr {
        var e2 = stack.pop();  // second expr is on top of stack
        stack.push( stack.pop() + " " + e2 + " " + $op.text);
      }
    | expr op = ('+' | '-') expr {
        var e2 = stack.pop(); // second expr is on top of stack
        stack.push( stack.pop() + " " + e2 + " " + $op.text);
      }
    | term // already on stack
    ;
term
    : '(' expr ')' // already on stack
    | ID { stack.push($ID.text); }
    | NUM { stack.push($NUM.text); }
    ;

ID:  [a-z]+;
NUM: [0-9]+;

WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler can't find the `Stack` class: you need to import it:

```
grammar Expr;

@header {
import java.util.Stack;
}

...
```

And you can't do things like `$term.text = result;`. You cannot re-assign the text from of a token or parser rule. Note that `$term.text` is just a shorthand notation for `$term.getText()`